# Ansible wrongly reports 'command not found' error

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and I cannot solve an error: I use the `ansible.builtin.shell` to call the `pcs` utility (Pacemaker). The pcs is installed on the remote machine, and I can use it when I ssh that machine, but Ansible reports a 'command not found' error with error code 127.

Here is my `inventory.yml`:

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    centos7:
      hosts:
        UVMEL7:
          ansible_host: UVMEL7
```

Here is my play-book, `TestPcs.yaml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Test the execution of pcs command
  hosts: UVMEL7

  tasks:
   - name: Call echo
     ansible.builtin.shell: echo
   - name: pcs
     ansible.builtin.shell: pcs
```

**Note**: I also used the echo command to verify that I am corectly using `ansible.builtin.shell`.

I launch my play-book with: `ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml TestPcs.yaml --user=traite`

And I get this result:

```
PLAY [Test the execution of pcs command] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [UVMEL7]

TASK [Call echo] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [UVMEL7]

TASK [pcs] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [UVMEL7]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "pcs", "delta": "0:00:00.003490", "end": "2022-03-10 15:02:17.418475", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2022-03-10 15:02:17.414985", "stderr": "/bin/sh: pcs : commande introuvable", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: pcs : commande introuvable"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
UVMEL7                     : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The pcs command is failing and in stderr, there is a 'command not found' error.

On the other and, when I ssh the machine and run pcs command, the command is executed and returns 1 which is different from 127. It is normal that pcs returns an error: I simplified the test case to the strict minimum to keep my question short.

I expect Ansible to have the same behavior: Error on pcs with return code 1.

Comment: "User wrongly thinks ansible should find a command wheras ansible clearly reports it's not found". <= where is that command installed in first place? Launching a command manually in your target shell does not guarantee the shell used by ansible will be able to use it. Note that ansible is using `sh` by default in a non-longin shell so without loading any user initialistion file (like `.bashrc`, `login`, etc)

Comment: @Zeitounator. When I `/bin/sh -c "pcs"` I get the same behavior as when I login the machine. pcs was installed cleanly through yum with root privilege.

Comment: When you login manually, are you logged on as the same user as Ansible? What's more, if you run `/bin/sh -c "pcs"` the new shell might be inheriting `PATH`. Where is `pcs` installed? Try `which pcs`.

Comment: Yes, when I login manually I use the same user as Ansible. When I do `which pcs`, I get `/usr/sbin/pcs`

Comment: Well now print out path in a default ansible shell task and I bet /usr/sbin is not in the default path.

Comment: @Zeitounator I used the `lookup('env', 'PATH')` to display my path and I can see there is `/usr/sbin` in it.

Comment: lookups run on the controller machine so the above returns the path for you current shell in which the ansible controller process is running. You want the path on your target (which might be totally different even if targeting localhost). Simplest debug: `echo $PATH` in a shell task and run in verbose mode (`-vvv`).

Comment: @Zeitounator You are right. When I just call `echo $PATH`, the `/usr/sbin/` is not present. But I still cannot figure out how to use this `pcs` in my Ansible script.

Comment: link the binary somewhere in the available path, source a file which contains an export with the correct path before you run your command, add an `environment` stanza with the correct path to your task....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to simulate what Ansible does (Based on remarks by @Zeitounator): `ssh <user>@<machine> '/bin/bash -c "echo $PATH"'`

I get my default PATH as explained in the manual page of bash. In my system sh links to bash.

I see that `/etc/profile` does the path manipulation that I need. However, it seems that because of the option `-c`, the bash is not started as login shell and therefore `etc/profile` is not sourced.

I end up doing the job manually:

```yaml
---
- name: Test the execution of pcs command
  hosts: UVMEL7

  tasks:
   - name: Call echo
     ansible.builtin.shell: echo
   - name: pcs
     ansible.builtin.shell: source /etc/profile && pcs
```

Which executes pcs as expected.

To sum up, my executable was not executed because the folder holding it was not listed in my `PATH` environment variable. This was due to the fact that `/bin/sh` aka `/bin/bash` was called with the flag `-c` which prevents sourcing `/etc/profile` and other configuration files.  The issue was 'solved' by sourcing manually the configuration file that correctly sets the `PATH` environment variable.